# How to use absolute paths in QML when importing JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am unable to identify how QML lets you use absolute paths when importing `Component`s and JavaScript files.

As far as I can understand, the only way to import is to either use relative paths or import `Component`s as a module.

But since I cannot make JavaScript functions as modules (or can I?), I can only do relative paths.

So my headers in most of my components are filled with code like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.2
import MyCompany.Gui 1.0

import "markets"
import "../../../../../../javascript/markets/MarketHelper.js" as MarketHelper
```

How am I able to let JavaScript be imported as nicely as QML modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following [format](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-qmldir.html#contents-of-a-module-definition-qmldir-file) to define a `JavaScript` file as part of a `qmldir` file:

```
<ResourceIdentifier> <InitialVersion> <File>
```

> Declares a JavaScript file to be made available by the module. The resource will be made available via the specified identifier with the specified version number.
>
> Zero or more JavaScript resource declarations may exist in the qmldir file, however each JavaScript resource must have a unique identifier within any particular version of the module.
>   Example:
>
> MyScript 1.0 MyScript.js

So, if you already have an existing `qmldir`, you can add the following line to it:

```
MarketHelper 1.0 MarketHelper.js
```

Then, you could use it like this:

```
import Market 1.0

// ...    

    Text {
        text: MarketHelper.priceOfOil()
    }

// ...
```

[Qt Quick Controls does this for calendar-related functionality](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Private/qmldir), for example, with [`CalendarUtils.js`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtquickcontrols.git/tree/src/controls/Private/CalendarUtils.js).

For more information:

- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-resources.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-topic.html
- http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-modules-identifiedmodules.html#locally-installed-identified-modules

Comment: Hi Mitch. I guess I was hoping to avoid using a module for *just* JavaScript functions. I thought it was not nice design to have JavaScript in a completely separate folder structure than the actual qml project. But I ended up doing it. So thank you.

Comment: Just to throw my two cents in: I think it's perfectly fine. You might find yourself adding other code in there in the future. :) It's certainly better than using absolute paths, anyway (and I'm not sure if that's even possible, which is why I didn't address it in my answer).